# compiling mingw for OS X

Tags: gcc, mingw, mingw32, mingw-w64

Following these steps https://gist.github.com/drewwells/ee5d42dc29b70b7b61af, it's possible to successfully install mingw32.

I'm trying to do this again with the gcc48 provided by brew `brew install gcc48 --with-all-languages` as a brew formula.

It appears gcc-core needs to be compiled with mingw32 headers. Here is the error output:

```
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking _mingw_mac.h usability... no
checking _mingw_mac.h presence... no
checking for _mingw_mac.h... no
configure: error: Please check if the mingw-w64 header set and the build/host option are set properly.
```

Code here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/48385